# Exporting chart drawn in plotly to pdf

Tags: plotly, plotly-python, xhtml2pdf

Basically my task is to create a report in python 2 (an oldy but goodie python 2.7.14) running on a headless (no display) Ubuntu 18 machine.

Plus - This is a very small machine, so a headless chrome solution or html2pdf (with it's heavy required installation of: wkhtmltopdf) is not an option... Hence, I am going for xhtml2pdf which should (on the paper) be my best option.

It does seem to work converting simple html file to pdf. However, using the following code to convert an html file created by plotly produces an empty page pdf (not an empty file, an empty A4 page):

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly
from xhtml2pdf import pisa 

labels = ['Oxygen','Hydrogen','Carbon_Dioxide','Nitrogen']
values = [4500, 2500, 1053, 500]
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Pie(labels=labels, values=values, hole=.3)])


html_filename = '/home/cpmuser/temp.html'
plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename = html_filename, auto_open=False)
source_file = open(html_filename, "rb")
source_html = source_file.read(1000000000)
print (len(source_html))
source_file.close()
output_filename = "/home/cpmuser/report.pdf"
result_file = open(output_filename, "wb")

pisa_status = pisa.CreatePDF(source_html, dest=result_file)
result_file.flush()
result_file.close()

print (pisa_status.err)
```

The temporary html file created by `plotly` seems to work fine. Although it is interactive, so maybe this is my problem?

Comment: It's or it's not interactive? Do you mind to tell which `plotly.__version__` are you using?

Comment: plotly.__version__ == 4.9.0   And I have found a flag that was supposed to render it non-interactive, but I think that the thing is the whole idea of plotly IS to be interactive. I should probably retreat back to drawing with something more basic...

Answer (score 1):

After reviewing numerous other packages, seems that plotly has it built in (employing another project: kaleido) - It simply calls it "Export to Image", which led me to the wrong conclusion it will be something like PNG/JPEG without selection of text (among other differences of raster/vector image/pdf). It exports it as pdf as can be :) text selection + vector images. Easy Peasy.